# not getting proper json formatted response from postman

Tags: postman, service-fabric-stateless

Please help me getting proper json response with postman. Is this an server error or just an formatting error please help me with the correct response.

Sample response :

```
"{\"Version\":{\"Major\":1,\"Minor\":1,\"Build\":-1,\"Revision\":-1,\"MajorRevision\":-1,\"MinorRevision\":-1},\"Content\":null,\"StatusCode\":200,\"ReasonPhrase\":\"OK\",\"Headers\":[],\"RequestMessage\":null,\"IsSuccessStatusCode\":true}"
```

But I wanted it in json format.

Comment: Can I see how it is sent from the server?

Comment: it's the server error.